# I want to get rid of 'article' confusion once and for all!

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I know there are innumerable questions about 'articles' on this and other sites on the Internet. I always try to learn them but some or the other way, they play tricks on me. In other words, I am never *positive* when I use them, in short. If two articles weren't enough to spin my head, the concept of 'zero article' or 'anarthrous' served as *another nail in the coffin!* :)

At times, I understand them perfectly but sometimes, I commit blunders! I want to solve this once and for all. I thought a lot and then am finally coming up with some sentences that would help clear my (and many others'?) doubts (hopefully).

**Help me understand the subtlety of these sentences.**

> 1. A [crown cork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_cork) of a bottle
> 2. A crown cork of the bottle
> 3. The crown cork of a bottle
> 4. The crown cork of the bottle

My understanding about those sentences:

> 1. Any crown cork of any bottle (but then is that crown *related* to that bottle is the question!)
> 2. I'm going to a shop with a bottle in my hand and asking for *a* crown cork that fits **the** only bottle in my hand
> 3. There is only one crown cork in front of me. I'm telling that this is **the** crown cork that can fit *any* bottle
> 4. The bottle and the crown cork both are *right* in front of me. That crown cork fits to only that bottle.

Answerers, please mind that I **haven't** introduced any bottle or crown cork previously! I'm ready for detailed answers. :)

Comment: What is the **crown** of a bottle? A **crown cork**? (just to make sure)

Comment: Some clues for advanced learners (on articles in general): What is unique? What is specific? What is generic? What is definite? What is indefinite?

Comment: @CopperKettle yes, crown cork, adding. In India, *crown* is understood but I'll now use this! Thank you! :)

Comment: I suppose that means 'bottle cap'.

Comment: You have four noun-phrases, not four sentences. I think without context it will be impossible to say exactly what each one means.

Comment: If you haven't introduced the item previously (and it isn't unique) then you have no business using 'the' -- use a demonstrative like 'this' instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A less formal use of "a crown cork of a bottle" - bottles are presumed to have only one mouth:

> 1. We were playing in the back-yard when Jim noticed something shiny, a roundish sliver of metal half-dug in the ground. "It could be **a** crown cork of **a** bottle ," I said.

The non-standard use fixed by Jim to the more formal **the** + **a** combination:

> 3. "I see," said Jim. "But bottles have only one crown cork, so you'd better say **the** crown cork of **a** bottle."

The "standard" use of the definite article in relation to things already introduced (the bottle) or implied (the crown cork):

> 4. "My dad once bought a very fancy bottle of beer, and after opening it he gave **the** crown of **the** bottle to me. It had a nice emblem on it," I said.

A sentence I constructed to make use of "**a** cork of **the** bottle":

> 2. "Oh, yeah," said he. "I wish that bottle had two mouths. Then you could get **a** crown cork of **the** bottle, and I could get **a** crown cork too.

According to *[this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20cap%20of%20a%20bottle%2Cthe%20cap%20of%20a%20bottle%2Ca%20cap%20of%20the%20bottle%2Cthe%20cap%20of%20the%20bottle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20cap%20of%20a%20bottle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20cap%20of%20the%20bottle%3B%2Cc0)* proposed by Damkerng, your options 1 and 2 are either non-existent or rare as hen's teeth. But I'm not totally sure. If I'm wrong, let someone correct me.

Comment: +1 for the story. Also, my thinking is close to yours! :)

Comment: @MaulikV - wait until a native speaker has his say, 'cause I'm unsure whether option 1 is really erroneous. (0: Damkerng in says it isn't (in the chat).

Comment: As a native speaker, 1) is quite natural, at least in speech. Using 'The' might be slightly better, but number one wouldn't catch my attention for being off.

Comment: Thank you, @Karen! I changed my wording a bit, to "more formal/less formal" to show that the a/a combination is possible.

Comment: I think 1 sounds a little weird, but I probably wouldn't think too much of it. I'd think you'd be more likely to hear 'from a bottle', than 'of a bottle' in that case, though.

Comment: Very interesting, @AlanThird! Would that imply that the cork could've been *inside* the bottle, one of many corks inside that bottle? Or would that mean "a cork of the kind used to close bottles"?

Comment: I think, since we're discussing bottles, the cork is almost always going to have been *in* a bottle at some time. So yes to your first question. I can't rule out that we'd use that phrase for the second too. I'm unsure.

Comment: @AlanThird - but a **crown cork** is sitting atop a bottle, it does not go inside, and would not unless persuaded.. I hope some native speaker would write his separate answer to throw some light on sentence 1.

Comment: I didnt know what a crown cork is. :) i think that it would still go with the bottle and so we'd say it's from a bottle. I'm not entirely sure, though.

Comment: I just looked up a crown cork. I would call that a bottle top, so there would never be any ambiguity. This is maybe why im struggling to think how we'd discuss it.

Comment: http://www.bullworks.net/virtual/infopages/crowncork.htm