# appendicitis is inflammation of the appendix -- why is there no definite article in front of "inflammation"?

Tags: articles

[Example (Wikipedia article)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appendicitis):

> Appendicitis is inflammation of the appendix.

Why do you think there is no definite article in front of ***inflammation***? Wouldn't it be better if there were one? For example, we say ***the handle of a knife*** because, even though we don't know what knife we are talking about, we do know that it has a particular handle that's part of the knife.

Comment: Which article would you choose to put there? "An" or "the"? And why?

Comment: 'the handle of a knife', 'the handle of the knife', 'a handle of the knife', 'a handle of a knife' -**all** mean different! :) I had asked this question [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/45995/i-want-to-get-rid-of-article-confusion-once-and-for-all)

Comment: The answer to a question I asked on ELU might be helpful http://english.stackexchange.com/q/240271/80039

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say Appendicitis is the inflammation of the appendix one might guess you talk of a definite inflammation of the appendix as in The inflammation of father's was incurable. In the sentence at hand "inflammation of the appendix" is used in a general sense and that is why it is used without the/an.

Answer (score 2):

Because when it describes some 'swelling' of a human organ, it is a **mass noun**.

> [inflammation (mass noun)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inflammation): *A localized physical condition in which part of the body becomes reddened, swollen, hot, and often painful, especially as a reaction to injury or infection.*

So, Appendicitis is inflammation of the appendix.

---

**NOTE:** It seems there is **no hard rule** that it's mass noun **always**. I've also observed that this word is used as a countable noun taking indefinite article. For instance..

> [an inflammation of the eye](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/inflammation)

Comment: Where's the difference between (an) inflammation of the appendix and of the eye. You first tell us that inflammation is a mass noun and using an article is wrong, and then you say that inflammation can be countable and takes an article. So, "an inflammation of the appendix" must be fine. I guess I'm saying this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I mean 'both' are okay and evident in authentic books/references. @Em1